# Empty layers while processing 'extract by location' in Python

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-processing

I have a folder with subdirectories containing shapefiles. I iterate in those folders to create a dictionary named liste_couches (['name of layer': complete path to shapefile']).

The code works fine when I directly call it, it returns a layer called 'fichiertraite' with the good extraction:

```
layer1 = QgsVectorLayer(liste_couches['geobase'], 'SamGamegie', 'ogr') #layer to be clip # liste_couches is a dictionary ['name of layer': complete path to shapefile']

tmp = processing.runalg('qgis:extractbylocation', layer1, lyTampon, [u'intersects'],0,None) #lyTampon is my intersect layer
lyc = QgsVectorLayer(tmp["OUTPUT"].decode('utf8').encode(enco), 'fichiertraite', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyc)
```

But when I nest it like this in a loop, it returns empty layers:

```
for couche, chemin in liste_couches.iteritems():


    lyCouche = QgsVectorLayer(chemin, couche, 'ogr') 

    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyCouche)
    tmp = processing.runalg("qgis:extractbylocation", lyCouche, lyTampon, [u'intersect'],0,None)
    lyc = QgsVectorLayer(tmp["OUTPUT"].decode('utf8').encode(enco), couche + '_tr', 'ogr')
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a typo in your loop when you're calling the `qgis:extractbylocation` algorithm.

You used:

```
[u'intersect']
```

when it should be:

```
[u'intersects']
```

Which is what you used in your first code. This may explain why you are not receiving any layers when you run it inside your loop.